# Alicloud Kubernetes cluster autoscaling with Terraform

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, autoscaling, alibaba-cloud

Is there anyone who successfully implemented Kubernetes cluster autoscaling with Terraform in Alicloud?
Is it possible with Terraform?

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy Container Service clusters on Alibaba Cloud by using Terraform
Here is how you can install Terraform on Alibaba Cloud.

- You must activate Alibaba Cloud Container Service.
- You must activate Alibaba Cloud Container Service and create an AccessKey for your account. Keep your AccessKey ID and AccessKey Secret properly.

Download Terraform from the [official website](https://www.terraform.io/downloads.html). Select the corresponding version and platform. In this document, install the Terraform on Linux (the procedure is similar to that of installing the Terraform on Mac OS X).

- Under Linux, click to download the terraform_0.11.3_linux_amd64.zip file.
- Copy the .zip file to an appropriate path (/usr/local/terraform in this example).
- Extract the .zip file and then get a binary file terraform.
- Create the following entries in the /etc/profile directory and add the path where the binary file resides (/usr/local/terraform in this example) to the PATH environment variable.

> export TERRAFORM_HOME=/usr/local/terraform
>
> export PATH=$PATH:$TERRAFORM_HOME

**Install Alibaba Cloud Terraform package**

Before using Terraform, an initialization operation is required to load Alibaba Cloud Provider. Run the following command in the template file directory:

```
terraform init
```

After the download is successful, the corresponding plugin is downloaded to the .terraform hidden directory in the current folder. If you encounter a network timeout problem during the loading process, follow the instructions to complete the manual installation of the plugin.

- Download the corresponding version and platform Provider from Alibaba Cloud Terraform Provider official download address. In this example, the Linux type is selected.
- Copy the downloaded file terraform-provider-alicloud_1.9.3_linux_amd64.zip to the Terraform installation directory /usr/local/terraform and extract it. The current directory gets Alibaba Cloud Provider terraform-provider-alicloud_v1.9.3_x4.
  Run the following command to test the working of Terraform. If Terraform is successfully installed, the following contents are displayed:

> $ terraform Usage: terraform [--version] [--help] [args]
>
> The available commands for execution are listed below. The most
> common, useful commands are shown first, followed by less common or
> more advanced commands. If you're just getting started with Terraform,
> stick with the common commands. For the other commands, please read
> the help and docs before usage.
>
> Common commands: ....
>
> All other commands: debug Debug output management (experimental)
> force-unlock Manually unlock the terraform state state Advanced state
> management

For more details [Click here](https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/67384.htm) for Alibaba Cloud Terraform Documentation

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
I know how to install and use Terraform
I asked about creating Kubernetes cluster Automatic Scaling
 with Terraform
Is it possible with Terraform Alicloud provider?